# When is a discontinuous function differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have the following question:

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x^2&\text{if }x\le2\\
mx+b&\text{if }x>2
\end{array}\right.$$

Find the values of m and b such that $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere.

Since this is a piece wise function, I was wondering how I'd go about this..

So what makes a discontinuous function differentiable?

Comment: You need to find $m$ and $b$ such that $f$ is continuous on $x=2$. Once you find'em, hopefully you can check it is also differentiable.

Comment: Hint: a differentiable function is never discontinuous. Can you find m and b such that the resulting function is continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others said in the comments above, never.

Therefore, for $f(x)$ to be differentiable at $x=2$, $f(x)$ should not be discontinuous. You need to find $m$ and $b$ to make the function continuous, i.e. such that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow2^+}f(x) = f(2)= \lim_{x\rightarrow2^-}f(x)$$

Simultaneously, these $m$ and $b$ should also make the derivative continuous at $x=2$, or 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow2^+}f'(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow2^-}f'(x)$$

I assume you know how to find the derivatives of $x^2$ and $mx+b$, for the latter case in terms of $m$ and $b$.